# Identification of an insect found in Edmonton, Alberta, Canada.

Tags: species-identification, entomology

It's 8.5mm long found in front yard. Unusual wing shape. Sorry about the images: the insect is so small my camera was struggling.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: That is a [caddyfish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caddisfly) (Thrichoptera).

Comment: Thank you but I'm looking for more specific answer,the species name or at least family

Comment: I know that. That's exactly why I wrote a comment, not an answer.